# two times inner join. but there is always syntax error

Tags: inner-join

```
SELECT E1.Name AS Empl, E2.Name AS HeadOfDepartment
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E1 INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS Dep
ON E1.DepartmentNr=Dep.DepartmentNr 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E2 
ON Dep.Head=E2.EmployeeNr
ORDER BY Dep.Name;
```

i don't know where is the error.

Comment: Are you using Access database?

Comment: @chris_techno25 yes, i use Access database

Answer (score 0):

Try following query.

```
SELECT E1.Name AS Empl, E2.Name AS HeadOfDepartment
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E1 INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS Dep
ON E1.DepartmentNr=Dep.DepartmentNr 
INNER JOIN E1 ON Dep.Head = E1.EmployeeNr
ORDER BY Dep.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Access database has a weird kind of syntax. Your SQL statement should work on most server type databases. Anyhow, try the code below and see if it works on your access.

```
SELECT E1.Name AS Empl,
       E2.Name AS HeadOfDepartment
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E1
INNER JOIN (DEPARTMENT AS Dep
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E2 
ON Dep.Head=E2.EmployeeNr)
ON E1.DepartmentNr=Dep.DepartmentNr
ORDER BY Dep.Name;
```